# Empty button with rounded edges

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit

I was wondering if I could make a button in Xcode that is just kind of a Rounded Rect with nothing inside so the background image would show in the button, but I need the Rounded Rect line around?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the default style with no text, or use a custom style. In that case you'll have to deliver all the graphics yourself including any rounded corners or borders.

Comment: Where can i make those graphics?